# "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time" in Magento

Tags: magento

i have a Magento site in which the checkout process worked fine until yesterday when i got this error message. does anyone know why this is happening?

the products are set to non-zero weights and i have enough in inventory too. i'm using the Fontis Australia extension. any help? thanks

Comment: I faced similar issue.I solved it myself also.The problem was.My development server was blocked ups website.when i grant a permission all works fine.Hope this helps some one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed. it seems Australia Post does not accept anything over 20kg (i didn't know this). the products were over 20 kilos and so the extension threw up the error message.